# How do you show a function is constant within a disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

If f is holomorphic at every point on the open disc $$D=\{z:|z|\lt1\}$$
I want to show that f is constant

Answer (score 0):

Consider $Re(f(z) \cdot (1 - i))$. This quantity always equals $10$. But if a holomorphic function has a constant real part in a connected open set, it must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is holomorphic, it satisfies the Cauchy–Riemann equations. Decompose $f$ in the usual way, into real and imaginary parts:
$$f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$$
We have $u+v=10$, so the starred equalities below hold:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=^*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=^*-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
Hence all partial derivatives involved are zero and $f$ is constant.